# Allow only stylesheets to be edited (no php files) on wordpress appearance editor

Tags: html, css, wordpress, tinymce, wordpress-theming

I have searched far and wide for an answer to this but cannot find one, which likely means it's not possible, but here goes:

Basically all I'm trying to achieve is for ONLY one style sheet to be available to edit on the wordpress appearance editor (the `editor-style.css` stylesheet).

Currently all the template files and the main `style.css` stylesheet are also available to edit on the backend, and I want to prevent that and just have the `editor-style.css` accessible so my clients can add some basic CSS.

I know I can hide the editor, and hide it when specific templates are currently in use, but this does not solve my problem.

I just don't understand why there's no hook or action (that i'm aware of) to alter which files are displayed on the editor.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't.

However, you would be able to create a plugin that would add custom CSS to override theme/child theme defaults. In fact, Google revealed one that seems to be pretty promising:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/

Disabling file editing and using this plugin would seem to accomplish your task. You could, alternatively, customize the Wordpress administration screen, but that is probably much more cumbersome of a task than it is worth.